# Insert pictures in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I just start learning Meteor. I put all my images in the root of "/public" folder. The images are named as "1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"....  I want to insert all the images to a collection "Images" by using for loop without putting a certain number as the for loop limit. So how can I make it detect how many images are in the public folder automatically?

Comment: So is the fact that those files are images any relevant or can it just be edited out? It seems that your question is simply "How to get the amount of files in a folder in Meteor" and that images are not relevant to it.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the amount of files in the folder "public" in Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a mechanism to get the list of images in the public folder, using the `fs` package will do this for you. Consider the following example which uses the package to read the public directory which is `/web.browser/app/` from the server (total unix path `/home/user/your_app_name/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/`).

After getting the folder list, filter the list to only get image files with the extension `.jpg`, then insert the images to your collection. For illustrative purposes the image document saved to the collection has the following simple schema example

```
{ _id: "v2PrCTPea6tM6JNHn", name: "1.jpg" }
```

To aid you with your final goal of inserting the images to the mongo collection, you can use the [batch-insert](https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert) Meteor package which enables the underlying mongo driver to insert of multiple documents. It works just like `insert()` but takes an array of objects to be inserted rather than a single object.

**#Installation**

In your meteor app directory run:

```
meteor add mikowals:batch-insert
```

**On server**

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs'),
    public_path = path.join(__meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir, "../web.browser/app"),
    files = fs.readdirSync(public_path),
    images = _(files).reject( function(fileName) {
        return fileName.indexOf('.jpg') < 0;
    }),
    imagesList = images.map(function (image){
        return { name: image };
    });

Images = new Meteor.Collection('images');

Images.allow({
    insert: function(){ return true };
});

var newIds = Images.batchInsert(imagesList);  // returns array of created _id values
```